# Spark scala running

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Hi I am new to spark and scala. I am running scala code in spark scala prompt. The program is fine, it's showing "defined module MLlib" but its not printing anything on screen. What have I done wrong? Is there any other way to run this program spark in scala shell and get the output?

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

object MLlib {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"Book example: Scala")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Load 2 types of emails from text files: spam and ham (non-spam).
    // Each line has text from one email.
    val spam = sc.textFile("/home/training/Spam.txt")
    val ham = sc.textFile("/home/training/Ham.txt")

    // Create a HashingTF instance to map email text to vectors of 100 features.
    val tf = new HashingTF(numFeatures = 100)
    // Each email is split into words, and each word is mapped to one feature.
    val spamFeatures = spam.map(email => tf.transform(email.split(" ")))
    val hamFeatures = ham.map(email => tf.transform(email.split(" ")))

    // Create LabeledPoint datasets for positive (spam) and negative (ham) examples.
    val positiveExamples = spamFeatures.map(features => LabeledPoint(1, features))
    val negativeExamples = hamFeatures.map(features => LabeledPoint(0, features))
    val trainingData = positiveExamples ++ negativeExamples
    trainingData.cache() // Cache data since Logistic Regression is an iterative algorithm.

    // Create a Logistic Regression learner which uses the LBFGS optimizer.
    val lrLearner = new LogisticRegressionWithSGD()
    // Run the actual learning algorithm on the training data.
    val model = lrLearner.run(trainingData)

    // Test on a positive example (spam) and a negative one (ham).
    // First apply the same HashingTF feature transformation used on the training data.
    val posTestExample = tf.transform("O M G GET cheap stuff by sending money to ...".split(" "))
    val negTestExample = tf.transform("Hi Dad, I started studying Spark the other ...".split(" "))
    // Now use the learned model to predict spam/ham for new emails.
    println(s"Prediction for positive test example: ${model.predict(posTestExample)}")
    println(s"Prediction for negative test example: ${model.predict(negTestExample)}")

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things:

You defined your `object` in the the Spark shell, so the `main` class won't get called immediately. You'll have to call it explicitly after you define the `object`:

`MLlib.main(Array())`

In fact, if you continue to work on the shell/REPL you can do away with the object altogether; you can define the function directly. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

def MLlib {
    //the rest of your code
}
```

However, you shouldn't initialize `SparkContext` it within the shell. From the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell):

> In the Spark shell, a special interpreter-aware SparkContext is
>   already created for you, in the variable called sc. Making your own
>   SparkContext will not work

So, you have to either remove that bit from your code, or compile it into a jar and run it using [`spark-submit`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: thank you for reply! i tried  MLlib.main(Array()) but its not working

Comment: When you say it isn't working, I won't be able to help you unless you say what you've tried and what error you're running into. Please provide more information so I can try to help you.

Comment: That's good you used MLib.main but you haven't left the SparkContext alone.  You don't  need the two lines of code that declare conf and sc. Every spark shell has a spark shell sc already